# oracle sql regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I have a table that has the values like this.

**ExpTable**

```
+--------+   
|expCol  | 
+--------+
|abc.abc |
|bcd.123 |
|efg.@/. |
+--------+
```

And what I wanted is that when the character after the period is a letter or number, the output will add a space after the dot like this:

**Expected Output**

```
+--------+   
|expCol  | 
+--------+
|abc. abc|
|bcd. 123|
|efg.@/. | --the value here stays the same because after the period is not a letter/number
+--------+
```

**I tried:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '.', '. ') from expTable WHERE /*condition*/
```

And as expected, everything including the last value 'efg.@/.' has got a space after the period. I dont know what to put in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. It searches for a `.` followed by a word character, and replaces it with a dot `.`, then a space and the matched character.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '\.(\w)','. \1') FROM ExpTable;
```

if you only want the first such occurrence to be replaced, you could specify it.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '\.(\w)','. \1',1,1)
```

Only thing to note is this would match a number,alphabet and underscore as well, if you don't want to consider `"_"` , use `[[:alnum:]]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in place of `\w`

[*Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be14b/5)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '\.([a-zA-Z0-9])', '. \1') AS expCol FROM expTable
```

OR

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '[.]([a-zA-Z0-9])', '. \1') AS expCol FROM expTable
```

Output

```
EXPCOL
abc. abc
bcd. 123
efg.@/.
```

LiveDemo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a6e0/31

Comment: This changes `abc/123` to `abc. 123` which is wrong. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1528cb/1) `[/.]` will match the `/` character or the `.` character - you want `[.]` or `\.` instead. Also, you do not want to use `REGEXP_LIKE` and then a different expression in `REGEXP_REPLACE` as `'abc.123.@/.'` will match the `REGEXP_LIKE` and then `REGEXP_SUBSTR` will change it to `'abc. 123. @/. '` which is, again, wrong.

Comment: sorry typing mistake

Comment: Still wrong as `[\.]` will match both \ and `.` characters [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b65cf7/1). Also, the edit did nothing to address the second error.

Comment: it's correct now I think @MT0 Thanks for different test case

Comment: Still wrong as `[\.]` will match both \ and `.` characters. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b65cf7/25) - look at the difference in the last row of the output. You want either `'[.]([a-zA-Z0-9])'` or `'\.([a-zA-Z0-9])'` as the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

`.` is a keyword in regex so you need put `\` in front of it

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(expCol, '\.(\w)', '. \1') from T
```

sqlfiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94ffec/1

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(EXPCOL,'\.\W','.')
abc. bc
bcd. 23
efg.@/.` Your output is wrong it replace 1st character after `.`

Comment: Guys you are right :(.I edit my answer 
. I so sorry about it.